# How to make date consistent through out the column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis

I have got a date in the below format but I am not able to figure out how I can make it consistent date throughout the column using Excel. I just need to get the year from the column so I can use it for generating graphs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXm4.png)
[image]

Comment: **Import** the data from the (likely) CSV source and, at the time of import, tell Excel that the incoming date format is `MDY`.  Else Excel is assuming the date format is the same as on your computer, which is probably `DMY`

Answer (score 0):

Enter `=Date(2020,5,31)` in a cell and it will display the date from May 31, 2020 in the format that your computer understands.

Using that format enter `=DATEVALUE("31/5/2020")` to see a number displayed, actually, 43982. Give the cell containing that number a custom date format and you can display it as "Sun, 31 May 31, 2020" or just "Sunday" or just "2020".

Presuming that you have either of these dates in a1, `=YEAR(A1)` will return its year, `MONTH(A1)` its month and `DAY(A1)` its day.

`=A1 + 1` will return "1 June 2020" , `=EDATE(A1, 3)` will add 3 months to it. `=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1+2),15)` will return a date for the 15th day of July, 2021.